# Rails Routes with Param - Controller ignoring param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable

I'm trying to figure out how to do filters for a datatable, so my thought in the interim is to have the an `<option>` apply a param to the URL, and the `basis` of the table to change, however, my Controller seems to be ignoring the parameters

```
def index
    @steam_games = SteamGame.all
    @steam_games = SteamGame.where("#{params[:genre]} = ANY (genres)") if params[:genre].present?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: SteamGamesDatatable.new(view_context, @steam_games) }
      end
  end
```

Is the best way I can think to apply it.

To test I also added in 
`get '/steam_games/:genre', to: 'steam_games_controller#index'` to the Routes, even though I'd like the URL to not change.

My debugger is showing

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  genre: indie
  controller: steam_games
  action: index
permitted: false
```

ON load I see `Parameters: {"genre"=>"indie"}` in the console.

Why is it that this isn't working? To note the `genres` is an ARRAY which is why I have the `where` as such, but that shouldn't change the parameter binding.

(Unsure what else to link reg. this).

It's POSSIBLE Datatables is trumping the `index` of the Controller, but I don't believe so since I feed it the list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is a strong params issue. You need to permit the params be used. You can try something like this in your controller.

```
def index
  @steam_games = SteamGame.all
  @steam_games = SteamGame.where("#{steam_game_params[:genre]} = ANY (genres)") if steam_game_params[:genre].present?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: SteamGamesDatatable.new(view_context, @steam_games) }
    end
end

private

def steam_game_params
  params.permit(:genre)
end
```

[Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)'s a link to `ActionController::Parameters` documentation.

Comment: I made the change (Which makes sense. I also didn't have it in permittable.) But now the array is continuously being returns as empty.

`SteamGame.where("'Indie' = ANY (genres)").count` works, and I can't see the output but I assume
SteamGame.where("'#{steam_game_params[:genre]}' = ANY (genres)") if steam_game_params[:genre].present?`
Is putting a similar query?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your new question, "Is putting a similar query?" ... Has your error changed since you added strong params? If the `.count` method works, then you should check your params are actually there. Use a `puts SteamGame.where("#{steam_game_params[:genre]} = ANY (genres)")` and check your output.

Comment: I'll try the output. Putting steam_params seems to have made it so it notices the params, but it constantly returns with `nil` - But if I would do the query for the same `genre` in Console, I will get a result.